# Global variable inside a function cant be access outside

Tags: javascript

If I understood it correctly, declaring a variable without using the keyword var inside a function will create a global scoped variable.

But I am getting this "ReferenceError: oopsGlobal is not defined" when accessing the variable from outside its container function.

```
,,,
 // Declare the myGlobal variable below this line
var myGlobal = 10 

function fun1() {
  // Assign 5 to oopsGlobal Here
  oopsGlobal = 5
}

// Only change code above this line

function fun2() {
  var output = "";
  if (typeof myGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += "myGlobal: " + myGlobal;
  }
  if (typeof oopsGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += " oopsGlobal: " + oopsGlobal;
  }
  console.log(output);
}

console.log(oopsGlobal) // ReferenceError: oopsGlobal is not defined
,,,
```

Comment: You didn't called/executed your `fun1()` therefore... you can guess correctly what happens. It's like `oopsGlobal` was never defined or assigned to any *Global* object. Call `fun1();` just before your console.log.

Comment: An assignment without `var` is not a declaration. It's just an assignment, and the global property won't get created until the assignment actually is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are never actually running `fun1()`. If you don't call a function, the code inside will never be executed.

ReferenceError:

```js
 // Declare the myGlobal variable below this line
var myGlobal = 10 

function fun1() {
  // Assign 5 to oopsGlobal Here
  oopsGlobal = 5
}

// Only change code above this line

function fun2() {
  var output = "";
  if (typeof myGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += "myGlobal: " + myGlobal;
  }
  if (typeof oopsGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += " oopsGlobal: " + oopsGlobal;
  }
  console.log(output);
}

console.log(oopsGlobal) // ReferenceError: oopsGlobal is not defined
```

No ReferenceError (note that `fun1()` is called **before** `console.log()`)

```js
 // Declare the myGlobal variable below this line
var myGlobal = 10 

function fun1() {
  // Assign 5 to oopsGlobal Here
  oopsGlobal = 5
}

// Only change code above this line

function fun2() {
  var output = "";
  if (typeof myGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += "myGlobal: " + myGlobal;
  }
  if (typeof oopsGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += " oopsGlobal: " + oopsGlobal;
  }
  console.log(output);
}

fun1()
console.log(oopsGlobal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written code, but never INVOKED it. `fun1` and `fun2` are never run. I added one line below that invokes the `fun1()` function which causes the assignment to happen.

This is more of an answer to provide a demonstration -- more than likely you do NOT want to actually write code that has global variables or side-effects like this. If you are writing software for the browser, using `window` or `globalThis` to store you global state also may make it more clear as well.

```js
// Declare the myGlobal variable below this line
var myGlobal = 10 

function fun1() {
  // Assign 5 to oopsGlobal Here
  oopsGlobal = 5
}

fun1(); // You wrote the functions previous, but you never CALLED them.

// Only change code above this line

function fun2() {
  var output = "";
  if (typeof myGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += "myGlobal: " + myGlobal;
  }
  if (typeof oopsGlobal != "undefined") {
    output += " oopsGlobal: " + oopsGlobal;
  }
  console.log(output);
}

console.log(oopsGlobal) // ReferenceError: oopsGlobal is not defined
```